# No mapping exists from object type System.Text.StringBuilder to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am try to create an application using asp.net (c#) In which the user will upload a single file (any data format doc, docx,pdf) using fileupload control.

And then I have to save the contents of the file in the database selected by the user. The structure of database is:

```
Field              DataType
id                 int
title              nvarchar(MAX)
body               varbinary(MAX)
bodyoverview       nvarchar(MAX)
postedon           date
```

The contents of the file will be saved in body attribute. Also I have the following code:

```
 protected async void Button_Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    string FileContent = String.Empty;
                    using(StreamReader inputStreamReader=new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
                    {
                        FileContent = await inputStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        
                        foreach (char c in FileContent.ToCharArray())
                        {
                            stringBuilder.Append(Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
                        }
                    }
                    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=Blog;Integrated Security=True");
                    string query = "insert into blogthumbnails values(@blogtitle,@body,@bodyoverview,@allowcomments,@commentscount,@postedon)";
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blogtitle", TextBox_Title_Of_The_Blog.Text);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@body", stringBuilder);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postedon", DateTime.Now.Date);
                    await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
                    try
                    {
                        int i = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if(i>0)
                        {
                            Label_File_Upload_Status.Text = "File Uploaded";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Label_File_Upload_Status.Text = "Please try again";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(SqlException sqlException)
                    {
                        Label_File_Upload_Status.Text = sqlException.Message.ToString();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception FileUploadException)
                {
                    Label_File_Upload_Status.Text = "Error in uploading file. Please try again. Error: "+FileUploadException.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Label_File_Upload_Status.Text = "Please select a file to upload";
            }
        }
```

But I am getting the error:

> No mapping exists from object type `System.Text.StringBuilder` to a known managed provider native type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `body` is of `varbinary` type thus data should be in binary format. You need to convert the result from `stringBuilder` into byte array first and then you can save it in you table.

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(stringBuilder));    
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@body", byteArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

By default StringBuilder is not a native type that can be mapped to NVARCHAR, TEXT, INT, DEC or other native sql types.

try these:

```
 sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@body", stringBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: I did this but now I am getting an error like this: "Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Answer (score 1):

This line: `sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@body", stringBuilder);` should be

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@body", stringBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: I did this but now I am getting an error like this: "Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. "